# all links unclickable after using python selenium

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

When I open a website on my internal server using Selenium, all links become unclickable when I try manually. Checkboxes and dropdowns still work. What is causing this? The website using Javascript and CSS along with HTML

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

#ask for credentials
email = raw_input("Username: ") #ask for username
pw = raw_input("Password: ") #ask for password

driver = webdriver.Ie("C:\\IEDriverServer.exe")

driver.set_window_size(1024, 768)
driver.get('someurl.com')


#fill in username
username = driver.find_element_by_id('loginForm:name')
username.send_keys(email) 

#fill in password
password = driver.find_element_by_id('loginForm:password')
password.send_keys(pw)

#click the login button
loginbutton = driver.find_element_by_name('loginForm:name')
loginbutton.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Comment: Which is the link in the provided code?

Comment: When I take out with the mouse and try to click on a link on the page.